# How to get app server address when deployed on tomcat in unix

Tags: java, unix, tomcat

I have to deploy a java war application on tomcat on unix system.
I am using getServletContext as below to get the path.

```
String webAppPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
```

When I was using the same code in eclipse on windows I was getting correct path & it was running fine.
But when deployed that in unix I got 
http://home/pratik/apache-tomcat-7.0.65/webapps/Job as my path instead of my server address say abc.com:8080/Job

How to get the server address along with my project name in java

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
request.getContextPath();
```

Comment: With the help of getContextPath() I am able to extract the project name(/Job).
But how to dynamically fetch server address with single command so that I would be able to get the complete path.
Say I run this application on 2 servers. So I need address in the format as:
pratik.com:8080/Job
kumar.com:8080/Job
Thanks.